# Error while inserting data into a table using package body

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting following error:

> 'ORA-06550: line 1, column 48:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:   := . ( @ % ;'

while trying to run below code:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY "PACKAGE_NAME" As

Procedure MAIN Is

BEGIN

LOAD_DATA;

END MAIN;

Procedure LOAD_DATA Is

V_LC_NARRATIVE VARCHAR2(50) :=     
'CDB_LETTER_OF_CREDIT_NARRATIVE.LOAD_DATA';
V_LC_STMT_ENTRY_NO VARCHAR2(50) := 'CDB_LC_STMT_ENTRY_NO.LOAD_DATA';
V_LC_HSCODE VARCHAR2(50) := 'CDB_LETTER_OF_CREDIT_HSCODE.LOAD_DATA';

BEGIN
insert into table_name
(
column1,
column2,...
)
SELECT 
 column1,
 column2,...
FROM Table_2 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;
COMMIT;

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' BEGIN ' || V_LC_NARRATIVE || ', END,';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' BEGIN ' || V_LC_STMT_ENTRY_NO || ', END,';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' BEGIN ' || V_LC_HSCODE || ', END,';

Exception
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ERROR_LOGGER ('PACKAGE_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME','',  SQLCODE,   substr(SQLERRM, 1, 500));

 END LOAD_DATA;

 END PACKAGE_NAME;
```

Comment: Why comma is here: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' BEGIN ' || V_LC_NARRATIVE || ', END,';`? Why not semicolon?

Comment: @cha, there is semicolon at the end....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
 execute immediate ' BEGIN ' || v_lc_narrative || ', END,';
```

to

```
 execute immediate ' BEGIN ' || v_lc_narrative || '; END;';
```

Comment: Rene helped rana :)